# How to change the active a tab on another window in a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, background, firefox-addon

I am trying to develop a **Firefox Extension**. I want to go to a browser tab on a different window. As I can understand from the Firefox Browser Extensions API I can change the focused window and I can change the active tab on the focused window separately. Thus, I wrote the code below to my background script to achieve this. However, when I use this code the browser first changes the focus to the window with the previously active tab of that window and then activates the tab that I want on that window. This behavior causes a glitchy feel.

```js
browser.windows.update(windowId, {focused:true})
browser.tabs.update(tabId,{active:true})
```

Can you suggest me a way to go to a specific tab on another window at one operation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Piro inspired me to first activate the tab and the change the focus of the window I tried the two code pieces below. However,  in both of them tab activation could not keep up with the windows focus change and resulted the same glitchy feel.

```js
browser.tabs.update(tabId,{active:true})
browser.windows.update(windowId, {focused:true})
```

```js
browser.tabs.update(tabId,{active:true}).then(() =>
 browser.windows.update(windowId, {focused:true})
)
```

Finally I just implemented the following which sleeps a while before changing the window focus. With optimizing the sleep duration to 50 ms I got a smooth experience.

```js
browser.tabs.update(audibleTabs[0].id,{active:true})
setTimeout(() => 
    browser.windows.update(window.id, {focused:true})
, 50);
```

Chrome Edit: I tried to run my extension on Chrome and experienced that 50ms sleep was not enogh for Chrome. Thus, I optimized the sleep time to 150ms for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is nothing way to do that with just one operation, so I think you need to activate the tab at first and focus to the window after tab activation, like:

```
async function focusToTab(tabId) {
  const tab = await browser.tabs.get(tabId);
  if (!tab.active)
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      const listener = activeInfo => {
        if (activeInfo.tabId != tabId)
          return;
        browser.tabs.onActivated.removeListener(listener);
        resolve();
      };
      browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(listener)
      browser.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true });
    });
  browser.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
}

focusToTab(1);
```

Comment: I tried your method and although it focused the right tab it first changed the browser than the tab resulting the same glitchy feel. However thank you for inspiring me to first try to activate the tab and then change the focus of the window.